# Calling a function as object variable?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I'm trying to construct a object with three strings and one function, which should return another value. But it seems like there is a problem with calling the function in an object.

For example

```
tom=new friend("One","Two","Three",list("tom"));

function list(who) {
    switch(who) {
        case "tom":
            return "four";
            break;
        ...
```

So calling list does not seem to work. At least this is the only thing I can imagine (except if I did some silly little typo).

Can I get this to work on another way? I appreciate every advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working for me:

```
function friend(a, b, c, d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}

tom = new friend("One", "Two", "Three", list("tom"));

function list(who) {
    switch (who) {
        case "tom":
            return "four";
    }
}

console.log(tom);
```

Assuming, of course, that you're defined friend the way I did, I don't see a problem. At least not with your `list` function.

Comment: Hm, yeah. It should be right indeed. But I guess I will set the fourth attribute to an new variable defined by another function. But thank you!